# ASP.NET C# Get Full path from file

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i get the full path from a file? In ASP.NET dont have the openfiledialog.
I try that code with the FileUploud:

```
Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName)
```

This works, but when i want another file give me a error, becouse the FileUploud upload the file, and i just want the path from the file.

I want save a image on database, and for that i need the path of the image.

Somebody can help me? (Sorry my english)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get the path of the file on the client user's machine?

Comment: You can't get path from client machine. `FileName` property will have just file name, not the path. Because it would be file name from client machine and path won't give you anything usefull information

Comment: I want save a image on database, and for that i need the path of the image

Comment: Do you want to get the path on client or on the server? Do you know the file relative path to your app?

Comment: I want the path from the cliente computer.

Comment: I think you'll want to read up on how the file upload process works. Try [this tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246), and if you have issues with that, update your question.

Comment: I dont want upload the file, i just want show the "open file dialog" for the user select a image and then retrive the Path from that image.

Comment: You can't get path from client computer. You can only have a file name of that file that user is selected. And the binary body of that file in `FileUpload.PostedFile` property. Sample of PostedFile usage - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the path from the client's machine. It is a security issue. The browser will only give you the file name. If you really need the path, you could probably write an extension for chrome/firefox and force the client to install / use it.

You should be able to save the image to a database without knowing where on the client the image came from. If you need that path to help you store it in a sub folder on the server you'll need to have the client select that location manually.

You could have a textbox with a "Copy upload path here" right below the input box that the client could then "upload" the file (don't actually post this data if you don't want it), and then copy/paste that location into the textbox and submit that string to the server.

Comment: OK tanks for de advice